# Select several polygons with the same identifier in GeoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geojson, select

I have a map application where:

- I load polygons as GeoJSON objects
- I draw all polygons in a single layer
- I highlight a polygon on mouse hover from a identifier list
- Some polygons have the same identifier ("idarsol")

I use fitBounds, getBounds et setStyle functions but, on mouse over, only the first polygon (found in the GeoJSON file) is highlighted...
I don't want to merge polygons with the same identifier for scientific reason. Is there another solution?

Here is code to create GeoJSON file from postGIS database :

```js
// create a new layer for "murs"
var lat_murs = create_geojson_layer('murs', 'num_mur', 'murs', '<?php echo $where_murs; ?> AND num_zone IN (3,4,8) ', '#a5c485');

function create_geojson_layer(table, id_arsol, type_arsol, cond, couleur){
    var url = "postgis_geojson.php?geotable="+table+"&geomfield=wkb_geometry&parameters="+cond;
    var json = loadJSON(url);   
    var lat_layer = new L.GeoJSON(json,
    {
        style: { "color": couleur, "weight": 1, "opacity": 0.5 },
        argsGeoJSON: { geotable: table, geomfield: 'wkb_geometry', parameters: cond },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
            idarsol='i'+type_arsol+'AJ'+feature.properties[id_arsol].padStart(6,'0');
            tab_sig[idarsol] = featureLayer;
        }
    }
    );
    return lat_layer;
}
```

Here is a part of the GeoJSON generated where you can see 3 M.1001 objects :

```js
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[0.717220280101286,47.4042990283296],[0.717220525253972,47.4043009931232],[0.717228227705038,47.4043017666837],[0.717231031505089,47.4043014945918],[0.717234953044399,47.4043011140299],[0.717235356104778,47.4043001418758],[0.717220439531643,47.4042981889541],[0.717220280101286,47.4042990283296]]]]}, "properties": {"ogc_fid":"127","id":"0","num_mur":"1001","num_zone":"4","num_sect":"2","image":"","operation":"LAT","annee":"2008","uc":"40832","base":"0","extrusion":"0","nu_mur_ea":"","periode":"12e-13e s.","inter_uc":"","fonction":"fondation","source_dat":"","phase":"phase 3 hôtellerie","ensemble":"","copiefid":"126","date_const":"12d","date_destr":"12d","dat_app":"1175","dat_disp":"1175","wkb_geometry":"010600002032BF0D0001000000010300000001000000080000007F8199ADEB1B2041C3B91AF0D3915941D6CC4ABAEB1B20410A7B08FED39159411F7EDCE4EC1B204104B27402D4915941CE65A250ED1B2041618A2100D4915941D20F5FE7ED1B20415A20E1FCD3915941FB8E54F5ED1B2041FA1BEAF5D391594190915FB2EB1B2041C2F81DEAD39159417F8199ADEB1B2041C3B91AF0D3915941","id_mur":"AJ001001"},"id":"0"},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[0.717247621321166,47.4043027785609],[0.717250687473728,47.4043034244505],[0.717253905681193,47.4043040963393],[0.717260687722119,47.4043055048087],[0.717267985280984,47.4043069564791],[0.717275652908286,47.4043075676018],[0.717284964325095,47.4043085975951],[0.717286992293016,47.404306725629],[0.717287436705935,47.4043063154025],[0.717287783364649,47.4043059531075],[0.717284551594815,47.4043056047898],[0.717271466448952,47.4043040361517],[0.717257685002896,47.4043025338603],[0.717248027758756,47.4043016481554],[0.717247621321166,47.4043027785609]]]]}, "properties": {"ogc_fid":"128","id":"0","num_mur":"1001","num_zone":"4","num_sect":"2","image":"","operation":"LAT","annee":"2008","uc":"40833","base":"0","extrusion":"0","nu_mur_ea":"","periode":"12e-13e s.","inter_uc":"","fonction":"fondation","source_dat":"","phase":"phase 3 hôtellerie","ensemble":"","copiefid":"127","date_const":"12d","date_destr":"12d","dat_app":"1175","dat_disp":"1175","wkb_geometry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id_mur":"AJ001001"},"id":"0"},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[0.717250687473728,47.4043034244505],[0.717247621321166,47.4043027785609],[0.717246800259271,47.4043050621408],[0.71723979196195,47.4043043641081],[0.717240706420535,47.4043008423558],[0.717235356104778,47.4043001418758],[0.717234953044399,47.4043011140299],[0.717231031505089,47.4043014945918],[0.717231130851508,47.4043017353291],[0.717232667611845,47.4043048068422],[0.717235007596266,47.4043058652513],[0.717246608859468,47.4043065494109],[0.717248952784434,47.4043061683421],[0.717250687473728,47.4043034244505]]]]}, "properties": {"ogc_fid":"129","id":"0","num_mur":"1001","num_zone":"4","num_sect":"2","image":"","operation":"LAT","annee":"2008","uc":"40831","base":"0","extrusion":"0","nu_mur_ea":"","periode":"12e-13e s.","inter_uc":"","fonction":"fondation","source_dat":"","phase":"phase 3 hôtellerie","ensemble":"","copiefid":"128","date_const":"12d","date_destr":"12d","dat_app":"1175","dat_disp":"1175","wkb_geometry":"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","id_mur":"AJ001001"},"id":"0"}
```

Here is code for highlighting object :

```js
// Zoom and highlight
var tab_sig = {};

var idarsol_sel=0;
var idarsol_sel_style={ "color": '#FF00FF' };
var highlight_style={ "color": 'red', "weight": 5, "opacity": 1 };

// zoom on object on the map
function zoom_on_arsol_feature(idarsol){
    if(tab_sig[idarsol]!=undefined){
        map.fitBounds(tab_sig[idarsol].getBounds());
    }
    select_arsol_feature(idarsol);
}
// highlight selected object
function select_arsol_feature(idarsol){
    if(tab_sig[idarsol]!=undefined){
            // style back for previous selected object
            if(idarsol_sel!=0){
                tab_sig[idarsol_sel].setStyle(idarsol_sel_style);
            }
            // get style for actual selected object
            idarsol_sel_style=tab_sig[idarsol].options.style;
            idarsol_sel=idarsol;
            tab_sig[idarsol].setStyle(highlight_style);
    }
    if(idarsol==0){
        if(idarsol_sel>0) tab_sig[idarsol_sel].setStyle(idarsol_sel_style);
    }
}
```

And the code to launch detection of hover (example for M.1001) :

```html
<span onmouseover="zoom_on_arsol_feature('imursAJ001001');" title="m1001">M.1001</span>
```

Link to test : https://marmoutier.univ-tours.fr/hotellerie.php#div1_2_1p2

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Please add more relevant code of how you create your GeoJSON layer and fill `tab_sig` array.

Comment: Your features have many properties. Which of those properties together uniquely identify a group of polygons you want to highlight at the same time, for example mentioned `M.1001`?

Comment: Yes, it's `num_mur` property in the GeoJSON file, which is called by the `create_geojson_layer()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since GeoJSON layer in question is not big, the simplest solution would be to iterate through all the layers/features of GeoJSON layer and set style for those that have desired `num_mur` property.

Code could the look something like this (not tested):

```
function setMurStyle(selLayer, style) {
  var numMur = selLayer.feature.properties.num_mur;
  lat_murs.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if (layer.feature.properties.id_mur == numMur) {
      layer.setStyle(style);
    }
  });
}

function select_arsol_feature(idarsol){
  if(tab_sig[idarsol] != undefined){
    if(idarsol_sel != 0){
      setMurStyle(tab_sig[idarsol_sel], idarsol_sel_style);
    }
    idarsol_sel_style = tab_sig[idarsol].options.style;
    idarsol_sel = idarsol;
    setMurStyle(tab_sig[idarsol], highlight_style);
  }
  if(idarsol == 0){
    if(idarsol_sel > 0) setMurStyle(tab_sig[idarsol_sel], idarsol_sel_style);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposition ! It should work... but it doesn't and I don't understand why :(


It works for first object (like before) if I don't get into `each` loop
```javascript
function setMurStyle(selLayer, style) {
 selLayer.setStyle(style);
}
```

The `each` loop is OK ; The `var num_mur` is OK ; The number of loops for each object is OK ; The test `layer.feature.properties.id_mur == numMur` is OK. But `layer.setStyle(style);` in your proposition doesn't work... :(

Comment: If you put proposed code from answer online in https://marmoutier.univ-tours.fr/hotellerie.php#div1_2_1p2, I can have a look why it doesn't work.

Comment: It's done. Thank you very much for taking time for me

Comment: Sorry, I tried to guess what's happening, but it's a bit too complex to be able to track the logic of events.

Comment: Never mind... I will continue to explore. Thank you very much for taking the time to watch.

Comment: I am furious! My problem was only due to the poor definition of the scope of js variables... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Rather be glad you finally found stupid mistake. If answer helped you solve your problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.

Comment: I don't know how... How can I mark this question as accepted ? I didn't found... sorry

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and

Comment: Done. Thank you for all.